# How to set max-width on amp-img in responsive mode?

Tags: css, amp-html

For an AMP article, I set my article body in a column of dynamic width (currently `30vw`). I'd like images to fill the column full-width, so I'm using `<amp-img layout='responsive'>`. This works fine, except for images which are narrower than the column - in this case, the `responsive` mode upscales them, which is not desirable.

I can fix this issue by setting smaller images to `fixed` layout. But where to stop? If I set all images to `fixed`, then the larger images will break out of the column. And I don't know the width of the column in px, so can't change the logic based on that.

In CSS, I could solve this simply using `max-width`:

```
<amp-img src="http://placehold.it/90x60" width="90" height="60" style="max-width: 90px" layout="responsive" alt="an image"></amp-img>
```

...but inline CSS is not allowed in AMP, and this fails validation.

I've explained the issue here: http://codepen.io/georgecrawford/full/XKOWgd/.

AMP HTML:

```
  <main>
    <p>'responsive' layout is fine when the image fits in the column:</p>
    <amp-img src="http://placehold.it/600x400" width="600" height="400" layout="responsive" alt="an image"></amp-img>

    <p>For smaller images, we use 'fixed' to avoid them being upscaled</p>
    <amp-img src="http://placehold.it/90x60" width="90" height="60" layout="fixed" alt="an image"></amp-img>

    <p>Otherwise:</p>
    <amp-img src="http://placehold.it/90x60" width="90" height="60" layout="responsive" alt="an image"></amp-img>

    <p>But we can't make all images fixed, in case they're bigger than the column width:</p>
    <amp-img src="http://placehold.it/600x400" width="600" height="400" layout="fixed" alt="an image"></amp-img>

    <p>...and we want the column width to be responsive, and set in ems. So what to do? Ideally, we'd use 'responnsive' layout for all images, but with a max-width of 100% (i.e. the parent container width).</p>
  </main>
```

CSS:

```
main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 30vw;
  background: lightblue;
}

amp-img {
  outline: 1px solid gold;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

Any clever suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

In your CSS, you could have:

```
.smImg {
    max-width: 90px;
}
```

Then in AMP HTML for the smaller images you could have:

```
<amp-img class="smImg" ... ></amp-img>
```

Or does this need to be dynamic as in you aren't manually creating each of these pages? In that case, it would be nice to know a little more detail to help you out.

Comment: It needs to be dynamic I'm afraid - we're producing hundreds of articles programatically, and images can be anything from 100px to 1000px wide.

Comment: What CMS system and language are you using? Another way to do it would be to add `layout=fixed` when the width of the image is less than some value like 500 or something like that.

Comment: It's self-authored, so I have full flexibility to add my own logic. But I don't know the width of the column on the server, so "some value like 500" can't ever be determined.

Comment: I think 320px might be a safe guess since thats the width of an iPhone4/5 and I would think that most people now have a phone larger than an iPhone 4/5.

Comment: Another way to do it would be to dynamically create the CSS for each page. Might be a better and more bulletproof way of doing it.

Comment: style not accepting...it's needs to define in html itself as width="50" height="50"

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this-

```
.halfwidth{
width:50%; text-align: center; padding:15px;  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Of course you don't have to set 50% width, your choice.
Include the image in a

```
<div class="halfwidth">
<amp-img src="http://placehold.it/90x60" width="90" height="60"  layout="responsive" alt="an image"></amp-img>
</div>
```

PS: never use incline styles. It is not valid in amp-html.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the image in a div and set the max-width of the div in your inline CSS:

```
<div style="max-width: 90px">
  <amp-img src="http://placehold.it/90x60" width="90" height="60" layout="responsive" alt="an image"></amp-img>
</div>
```